# @Entity class name cannot found in @Dao file in Room Database Android

Tags: android, android-room

As per this image I'm getting all employee list from the table. But when I'm calling @Entity class it'll throw an error.

**The error is "Cannot resolve symbol"** 
[image]

Please help me with this error.

Comment: Do you have an `@Entity` whose table is named `NewEmp`?

Comment: you have to annotate your `NewEmp` as an entity

Comment: okay dear friends, I understand what exactly the problem. Thank you.